# how to use recent facebook SDK in android?

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I am developing an app which can log in facebook and write post on my wall ..
I am using this tutorial : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

it's working fine but eclipse tell me all of this methods are deprecated ..

Now how can i replace it with recent version ??

Thanks in advance :)

```
public void loginToFacebook() {
        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

        if (access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        }

        if (expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }

        if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            facebook.authorize(this,
                    new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                    new DialogListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            // Function to handle cancel event
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                            // Function to handle complete event
                            // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                            editor.putString("access_token",
                                    facebook.getAccessToken());
                            editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                    facebook.getAccessExpires());
                            editor.commit();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(DialogError error) {
                            // Function to handle error

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                            // Function to handle Facebook errors

                        }

                    });
        } else {
            postOnWall(quote);
        }
    }

    // ==============================================================================

    public void postToWall() {
        // post on user's wall.
        facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
            }
        });

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    public void postOnWall(String msg) {
        Log.d("Tests", "Testing graph API wall post");
         try {
                String response = facebook.request("me");
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("message", msg);
                parameters.putString("description", "test test test");
                response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, 
                        "POST");
                Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
                if (response == null || response.equals("") || 
                        response.equals("false")) {
                   Log.v("Error", "Blank response");
                }
         } catch(Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
```

Comment: The best solution is provided by the facebook docs itself

Comment: Try this one https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading/#20to30